# How to skip an error in loop while preserving the missing element as a blank column?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, try-catch, skip

I have the following chunk of data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(c(0.640372781, 0.54596394, 0.364612178, 0.554321638, 
0.623891566, 0.299900389, 0.629781465, 0.502673674, 0.414942748, 
0.485381455, 0.629032253, 0.201974626, 0.549820206, 0.49277897, 
0.299640651, 0.443151949, 0.506297992, 0.259198111, 0.635090505, 
0.597640686, 0.430193856, 0.631067648, 0.662995875, 0.391062922, 
0.632248042, 0.627503454, 0.432827825, 0.418849204, 0.612201188, 
0.227470395, 0.556520484, 0.6095603, 0.414923451, 0.57634896, 
0.543780581, 0.320027087, 0.655818488, 0.648937123, 0.497094053, 
0.429772696, 0.632386262, 0.270060224, 0.564427852, 0.456642259, 
0.492407708, 0.436349654, 0.616355794, 0.248897538, 0.642866477, 
0.555022037, 0.358901689, 0.53184597, 0.606299729, 0.342449093, 
0.667681177, 0.506448197, 0.370292817, 0.555462276, 0.642302168, 
0.42487856, 0.649249462, 0.544035494, 0.394793334, 0.383522657, 
0.557789563, 0.220189788, 0.636151283, 0.547825201, 0.391789202, 
0.653913292, 0.649412792, 0.452257495, 0.648866884, 0.535907987, 
0.392093314, 0.724788138, 0.674157973, 0.494385979, 0.673032345, 
0.450686601, 0.369089571, 0.397124065, 0.502592807, 0.197922003
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1025049600, 
1025136000, 1025222400, 1025481600, 1025568000, 1025654400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 
14L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("AN8068571086", "BMG3223R1088", 
"BMG4388N1065", "BMG6359F1032", "BMG7496G1033", "BMG812761002", 
"CA88157K1012", "CH0044328745", "CH0048265513", "GB00B4VLR192", 
"GB00B5BT0K07", "GB00B6SLMV12", "GB00BFG3KF26", "GB00BVVBC028"
)))
```

And this code:

```
    ######## INPUTS ######

a <- 0.5
b <- 0.6

results <- list() # list containing loop results

#######################


for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {


  input <- as.matrix(data[i,])

  #extract column names with a value between a and b  

  stocks <- matrix(colnames(data[,which(input > a & input < b)]))

  # make a vector with new name for the output
  date   <- head(rownames(input), n=1)

  #rename column  
  colnames(stocks) <- date

  #export to list under "date" name
  results[[date]] <- stocks

}
```

If you run it exactly as it is you will get this error:

```
Error in matrix(colnames(data[, which(input > a & input < b)])) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(j, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(j, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

This comes from the third row in `data` which contains no values between 0.5 and 0.6

```
matrix(colnames(data[,which(input > a & input < b)]))
```

After running the above code i run this, which merges all my data together and prepares it for other calculations:

```
# merge all results in a list 
max_length <- max(sapply(results ,length))

final_results <- sapply(results, function(x){
  c(x, rep(NA, max_length - length(x)))
})
```

i need a way to skip that error while still preserving the date name as a blank column in `final_results`. I am thinking maybe an `if` function such that if there are no values that lie between `a` and `b` an empty matrix of (1x1) is created with the `colname = date` which should be stored in `results` list.

another option would be using `tryCatch` but that will omit the date entirely and between the thousands that i have here it will be impossible to find missing columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `tryCatch` function that processes your error by returning a matrix with NA value you would get a column with the appropriate date as a name that only contains NA in your `final_results`. However this would process all errors in the same way so may not be the best solution if your data could throw up different errors.

```
    stocks <- tryCatch(matrix(colnames(data[,which(input > a & input < b)])), 
                       error = function(e) matrix(NA))
```

Comment: Didn't know you can use trycatch that way. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution to your task:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(data)
DF <- apply(DF, 1, function(x) {
  ifelse(x > a & x < b, x, NA_real_)
})
```

Result of this is:

```
> DF
             2002-06-26 2002-06-27 2002-06-28 2002-07-01 2002-07-02 2002-07-03
AN8068571086         NA  0.5459639         NA  0.5543216         NA         NA
BMG3223R1088         NA  0.5026737         NA         NA         NA         NA
BMG4388N1065  0.5498202         NA         NA         NA  0.5062980         NA
BMG6359F1032         NA  0.5976407         NA         NA         NA         NA
BMG7496G1033         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
BMG812761002  0.5565205         NA         NA  0.5763490  0.5437806         NA
CA88157K1012         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
CH0044328745  0.5644279         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
CH0048265513         NA  0.5550220         NA  0.5318460         NA         NA
GB00B4VLR192         NA  0.5064482         NA  0.5554623         NA         NA
GB00B5BT0K07         NA  0.5440355         NA         NA  0.5577896         NA
GB00B6SLMV12         NA  0.5478252         NA         NA         NA         NA
GB00BFG3KF26         NA  0.5359080         NA         NA         NA         NA
GB00BVVBC028         NA         NA         NA         NA  0.5025928         NA
```

If you want to drop the columns that are all `NA`s then you can filter them like this:

```
DF <- DF[
  , apply(DF, 2, function(x) {
  sum(is.na(x)) != length(x)
})]
```

Result after the filtering is:

```
> DF
             2002-06-26 2002-06-27 2002-07-01 2002-07-02
AN8068571086         NA  0.5459639  0.5543216         NA
BMG3223R1088         NA  0.5026737         NA         NA
BMG4388N1065  0.5498202         NA         NA  0.5062980
BMG6359F1032         NA  0.5976407         NA         NA
BMG7496G1033         NA         NA         NA         NA
BMG812761002  0.5565205         NA  0.5763490  0.5437806
CA88157K1012         NA         NA         NA         NA
CH0044328745  0.5644279         NA         NA         NA
CH0048265513         NA  0.5550220  0.5318460         NA
GB00B4VLR192         NA  0.5064482  0.5554623         NA
GB00B5BT0K07         NA  0.5440355         NA  0.5577896
GB00B6SLMV12         NA  0.5478252         NA         NA
GB00BFG3KF26         NA  0.5359080         NA         NA
GB00BVVBC028         NA         NA         NA  0.5025928
```

Comment: @Alex Bădoi: Does that make sense to you?